# SEO impact of 301 permanent redirecting a domain to a sub-directory of another domain?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, subdirectory

I had my own experience of 301 permanently redirecting a domain to another (every page mapped) and Google properly worked everything out and it never had any problem SEO-wise. However, what if I'm redirecting a whole domain to the sub-directory of another domain in the same manner?

For instance, `http://www.example.com/` 301 to `http://www.another.com/example/`.

And everything underneath is correctly mapped such that `example.com/something/somepage.php?a=1` is 301 permanently redirected to `another.com/example/something/somepage.php?a=1`.

Etc.

Does anyone have any experience in this situation? Would it all work out good with regards to SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no different then any other 301 redirect. The search engines will associate the old URL with the new URL. This means links and PageRank will be carried over to the new URLs (minus a small amount of PR) and the new URLs will eventually replace the old URLs in the search results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but may I know if you had any first-hand experience about this or are you just extrapolating?

Comment: If you search this site you will see this come up often. It's a common question/issue with SEO. Doing a 301 redirect has been confirmed by Google for a long time now.

Comment: I searched through the site and googled for a bit but never found anyone redirecting a top level domain to a sub-directory of another domain. People seem mostly doing redirects from sub to top or top to top or sub to sub but few do top to sub. I know how things work on the same level but this is a downgrade in hierarchy so I'm not so sure, especially with years of work at stake. I want to know more than just the textbook lines. If anyone can point me to some more info or practical cases than just general sense that would be great.

Comment: The hierarchy doesn't matter. It all works the same. You're making it more complex then it really is.